# Using two ngRepeat's in a single tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can we use multiple ngRepeats in a single html tag? like the below code:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]" ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]" ></li>
</ul>
```

or

Can we Differentiate two different functionalities in the same ngRepeat by using &&? like the below code:

```
<ul>
<li ngrepeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] && j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]" ></li>
</ul>
```

My Purpose is to create a 10*10 mathematics tables, i wanted to repeat 1-10 numericals in one column of a table and the number that is going to be multiplied in another column. So i need your help..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry took a while to add code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple ngRepeat but repeater should be different. For eg:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in footest">
    <div ng-repeat="bar in bartest">
       {{bar.prop}} {{foo.prop}}
    </div>
</div>
```